# console.log() not showing in any browser in angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, angular

This is an ongoing angular OTA project. All the logging worked before, until suddenly they stopped working. None of the previously written console.log are outputting anything in the browser console.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Hiiiii');
    this.imgUrl = this.allapi.imageUrl;
    this.journeyType = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('journeyType'));
    this.bookingData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('payload'));
    if (this.bookingData.FareBreakdown.length > 0) {
      this.fareBreakDown = this.bookingData.FareBreakdown;
    } else {

    }
    this.calculateLayover();

    sessionStorage.setItem('promoApplied', JSON.stringify(this.promoApplied));

    if (this.journeyType == 3) {
      this.layover_multi = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('layoverMulti'));
      this.multiCityPlaces = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('multi_places_list'));
    }
    this.getFareBreakDown();
  }
```

In the ngoninit() the first console.log is not showing any output in the browser.

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5pvvrq

Comment: Is that file running on the browser?

Comment: Looks like `ngOnInit()` is not getting called.

Comment: Yeah, this is code of an angular component.

Comment: @SudhirOjha that is not the case I think. Not only ngOnInit(), none of the function's consoles are displaying anything, which previously worked fine btw.

Comment: I suspect you disabled log on chrome

Comment: @SouravBhowmik Is it possible to provide a stackblitz where *I/we* can reproduce it?

Comment: @Mindless No man, it's enabled. My other projects are showing consoles on chrome.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I don't think so :( . But I am trying. Is there any system files of angular that I can provide to you? For better understanding maybe?

Comment: all component code Maybe?

Comment: @SouravBhowmik Not duplicate but have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: add `debugger;` after `console.log('Hiiiii');` and refresh the page.I think your page not fired.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I already checked it. It was a chrome extension file, they logged it using chrome extension's developer mode. I can't do that in an angular project, can i?

Comment: it doesn't matter what they are using, you have some projects showing the log and some don't, so i don't think its a matter of extension

Comment: @SouravBhowmik Post the *(full)* component code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your index.html, `<script src="https://scripts.sandbox.bka.sh/versions/1.0.0-beta/checkout/bKash-checkout-sandbox.js"></script>` this line broke your code. Because override console.log function in this js. Remove this script if you dont use.

https://angular-8vvejy.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! It worked. Can you please explain, why this worked?

Comment: If you review the contents of the ".js" file above, you will see that many functions of the "console" object are "overrided" in this file. For example, `console.log = function (args) {
this.cacheargs = args;
return null;
} `.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure info is checked in default levels

[image]

Comment: checked them already. It's just as you have shown in my browser too, its labelled as default. I have 5/6 similar types of angular projects. I am facing this problem in some of them, others are working fine

Comment: Can you show abit more of the code? I don't see anything wrong with this code, what if you remove rest of the code and just leave ngOnInit() { console.log('hi'); }

Comment: Makes no difference. It's not a matter of one perticular component rather of the whole project.

Comment: well that's why we ask you to post more code

Comment: edited the main post with a stackblitz link